# IC identification - Analog Devices IC with top marking “A0 S”

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Please help me to identify this IC. It is an Analog Devices chip in the MSOP-8 package.

The top marking says "A0 S". It's used in a high-speed data collection card.

[image: photo of components on PCB]

Comment: https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/AD8475BRMZ?qs=%2FtpEQrCGXCwSP5ivtGCt%2Fw%3D%3D
Wild guess that came up in google search. Matches the package and the purpose. This is all you can count on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably [AD8656](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8655_8656.pdf), a low noise precision op amp.

[image]